# Pass json object as keyed message to apache kafka

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I have a json object which have different states of an order. I wanted to push this to apache kafka. The sequence is crucial as I have consumer set up which consume the data. I planned to use order id as key to the message as it will store in same partition in sequence.

```
data = [{"id": 1, "orderId": "A123","status":"PLACED"},{"id": 2, "orderId": "B123","status":"PLACED"}
{"id": 3, "orderId": "A123","status":"DISPATCHED"}]

from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=os.environ['KAFKA_BROKER_URLS'],security_protocol="SSL")
for item in data:
    d = json.dumps(item)
    future = producer.send(topic,key=item['orderId'], value=d)
```

But I am getting assertionError in producer. I even tried

```
d = json.dumps(item).encode('utf-8')
future = producer.send(topic,key=item['orderId'], value=d)
```

also by defining the value serializer in initialization code like

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=os.environ['KAFKA_BROKER_URLS'],security_protocol="SSL",value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
```

All of them are giving the same error.
If I remove key and pass the data like

```
d = json.dumps(item).encode('utf-8')    
future = producer.send(topic,d)
```

This is working and message is getting pushed to kafka and displays in consumer side. But I want to pass key, for maintaining the sequence of the same order id. How do I solve it?

Update 1:

Here is the error:

```
{
  "errorType": "AssertionError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/producer.py\", line 56, future = producer.send(topic,key=item['orderId'], value=d)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py\", line 572, in send\n    assert type(key_bytes) in (bytes, bytearray, memoryview, type(None))\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you share the full error trace?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Added error log.